# Google Chrome Instant Type options

Tags: google-chrome

In the Google Chrome dev channel (version 10.0.612.3) when you go to about:flags there is the option to enable instant type, and there are three "modes":

- Verbatim
- Predictive
- Predictive no auto-complete

What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this article here](http://chromestory.com/2010/12/selecting-your-favorite-instant-search-type-chromium-labs/).

> - **Verbatim:** This will load results in your browser window as you type them.
> - **Predictive:** This will load results in your Omnibox and load then in your browser.
> - **Predictive no auto-complete:** Search suggestions will appear in a drop-down but not in the Omnibox.

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. If the site goes down, the answer becomes useless.